# Creating objects from user input - constructor requires parameters of different types

Tags: java

**Background:** I've been asked to create a project that involves multiple classes that store different information, followed by a menu that allows users to create objects of each class and call various methods from each (i.e. 'average of all numbers stored' etc.)

I've set up a 'menu' class, with a scanner allowing for user input, that prints a list of keywords for users to type in to select an option. So 'type 'ClassA' to create ClassA' etc. I've then stored an array of all possible keywords. User input is stored in instance variable 'keyword' and checked against array for accuracy.

Once it's confirmed, I then want to set up an 'if' loop that will call a method for each possible keyword. So for example

```
private void processKeyword() {
    String keyword = getKeyword();
    if (keyword.equals("keyword1")) {
       createClass1();
    }
    if (keyword.equals("keyword2")) {
        Class1.Method1();
    }
```

etc etc. I then can set up private methods within the menu class that allow me to do these things.

**Problem:** The problem I have is that some of the constructors and methods require parameters of both integer and string type. The scanner stores all input as strings, and asking for parameters straight from the method (let's say createClass1()) stops me from calling it from the if loop.

Anybody have any ideas how I can get around this roadblock?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't give us a lot to go on, so here's a simplistic answer.

Just make more local variables for your classes you create.  Then call them when needed.

```
private void processKeyword() {
   String keyword = getKeyword();
   Class1 aClass; // variable here
   if (keyword.equals("keyword1")) {
      aClass = createClass1();  // which must be assigned
   }
   if (keyword.equals("keyword2")) {
      aClass.Method1(); // call it
   }
```

Probably you want to call `new Class1()` instead of `createClass1()` so you can pass some parameters to the constructor.  That's the next step -- calling ctors with different parameters.  But first I think you should get one class working with one type of parameter.  Any type you like, whatever seems easiest.

Then post a new question and what you've actually got.  Explain where you're going to get these new parameters from (you don't say in your OP).  This isn't hard, just a little tedious with all the different possibilities.  Stick with it and it will get done.